# Label above d3 chart itself

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to put label above chart itself as if it's heading, like "Chart".
When i try to position label on wanted position, it gets cut off, like it goes "out of bounds" of sorts.
 I seen numerous examples of positioning text and they are more / less like i did. But i ain't getting same results. Mind you i'm newbie at this d3 stuff.
 Other thing that is bothering me is that i added arbitrary numbers to sort of "line up" bars. Like in **x** and **y** coords. Is this ... ok? I mean it's been added to all bars in a chart and for example without adding it, bar with value of 31, isn't high enough to reach **y** axis to 31 ... Beside answering me about how to position label / caption above chart, can you review my code?

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/codename11/pen/zYxwzqv).
Here is the code itself:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.14.2/d3.js"></script>

    <style>
        svg{

            padding: 20px;
        }

        text{
            fill: green;
        }

        rect{
            width: 5px;
            fill: navy;
        }

        g{
            border: 1px solid green;
            font-size: 0.5em;
        }

        .bar:hover{
            fill: whitesmoke;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        #demo{

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="demo"></div>

    <script>

        const dataset = [12, 31, 22, 17, 25, 18, 29, 14, 9];

        const w = 500;
        const h = 115;
        const padding = 10;

        const svg = d3.select("#demo")
                      .append("svg");

        const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([dataset.length, 0])
                        .range([h/2.23, 0]);

        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .range([h, 0])
                        .domain([d3.min(dataset), d3.max(dataset)]);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d, i) => (i * 5.21)+20)
            .attr("y", (d, i) => (h - 3 * d)-20)
            .attr("height", (d, i) => (3 * d)+20)
            .attr("class","bar")
            .append("title")
            .text((item,i)=>{
                return item;
            });

            svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", w/6)
                .attr("y", (h / 12))
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "11px")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Chart")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0, -2)");

            const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(2);//Kolicina crtica, pr. 0,5,10 isl..
            svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20," + h + ")").call(xAxis);

            const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
            svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)").call(yAxis);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is how i want to position string "Chart": 
[image: label / caption]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and found several errors. 
Since you are new to D3.js I recommend you understand how the scales work. This might help https://www.d3indepth.com/scales/.

For your problem,

1. First, create a `g` inside your svg for drawing the chart to separate it from your title. It is best to transform it by the margin top and left like:

```
const m = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 };

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + m.left + m.right)
    .attr("height", h + m.top + m.bottom)
const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + m.left + "," + m.top + ")");
```

All chart related elements such as the axis, the rectangles should be drawn in the `g` (this is just good practice and helps separate code).

2. Since you want to draw a bar chart, your x-scale should be a band type scale i.e. use `scaleBand()` like:

```
let xScale = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, w])
          .padding(0.1);
```

3. The domain for the xScale will be an array of indices for the `dataset` like:

```
xScale.domain(dataset.map(function(d,i) { return i; }))
```

4. The `yScale` needs to be `scaleLinear()` and the range is set to the height, while the domain is set to the extent of the values like:

```
let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([h, 0]);

yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset)]);
```

Note- you can change the `0` in the domain to be whatever minimum value of y-axis you would like. But classically, barcharts start from `0` so I kept it so.

5. Once you have all this you should draw your axis first

```
// draw the axis
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale); 
g
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(xAxis);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
g
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

Again good practice to draw axis first.

7. Draw the rectangles using the `append("rect")` as you did only now use the `xScale` and `yScale` to position the `x` and `y` and then use the difference in the height and the yScale value to get the `height`, while using the `xScale.bandwidth()` function to get the `width` like so:

```
//draw the rectangles
g
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i)) //the displacement along the x is dependendant on the index and the xScale
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d)}) //the displacement along the y is dependant on the value and the yScale
  .attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d); }) //the height is the difference between the displacement down and the height of the chart h
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth()) //the width of the rectangles is dependant on the bandwidth
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .append("title")
  .text((item, i) => {
    return item;
  });
```

8. Lastly add the chart title. The chart title is positioned in the middle of the svg using the `w/2` for the `x` attribute, while using the `m.top` as the `y` attribute to position it right above the chart `g`.

```
svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", w / 2) //positions it at the middle of the width
  .attr("y", m.top) //positions it from the top by the margin top
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("fill", "green")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Chart");
```

Note- the class `.title` is added to control the font-size etc. but it can be done in the attributes as well.

Here is the full snippet.

```js
const dataset = [12, 31, 22, 17, 25, 18, 29, 14, 9];

const w = 500;
const h = 115;

//set the margins
const m = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 };

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + m.left + m.right)
    .attr("height", h + m.top + m.bottom)
 const g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + m.left + "," + m.top + ")");

// the xScale for the bar chart will be a band scale
let xScale = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, w])
          .padding(0.1);

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([h, 0]);

//Since the domain is about the index of the values,
// the domain must be an array of the indices for the x-axis scale
xScale.domain(dataset.map(function(d,i) { return i; }))

//for the y-axis scale since it is a linear scale you just
// mention the array extent as the domain
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset)]);

// draw the axis
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale); 
g
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(xAxis);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
g
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(yAxis);

//draw the rectangles
g
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i)) //the displacement along the x is dependendant on the index and the xScale
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d)}) //the displacement along the y is dependant on the value and the yScale
  .attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d); }) //the height is the difference between the displacement down and the height of the chart h
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth()) //the width of the rectangles is dependant on the bandwidth
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .append("title")
  .text((item, i) => {
    return item;
  });


//Draw the  Chart Label:
svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", w / 2) //positions it at the middle of the width
  .attr("y", m.top) //positions it from the top by the margin top
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("fill", "green")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Chart");
```

```css
svg {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* This controls the Chart Title */
text .title{
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* This controls the axis text size */
.axis text {
  font-size: 8px;
}

rect {
  fill: navy;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I'm sort of getting it , but i still struggle with understanding relation between y coord and returned value of yScale. For example when i console.log(d, yScale(d)); it, i'm getting value from an array and second would be a value in pixels which represents value of a bar displacement looking from top? Is that what yScale calculates? Then paints it, excluding "displacement"? I'm new to d3, so i'm not even sure is this rightly phrased question ...

Comment: Hi @VeljkoStefanovic. You are correct the `yScale(d)` will give you the displacement in pixels from the top of the `g` because the range is set to `range([h,0])`. This value tells the `.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d)})` to move the rectangle down by `yScale(d)`px. The height of the rectangle is then calculated as the difference between the total height `h` and the displacement from the top i.e. `yScale(d)` as `.attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d); })`. Hope this helps you understand better.